# restore postgreSQL database on Django project

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm working on an application that runs on **Ubuntu 18.04**, it consists of Django App and PostgreSQL server, each on runs in a separate Docker container.
I created a backup for my database, so I can keep it and runs it on a test server for test cases.
Now I'm moving my backup database to another test server, but the problem is when I run:

```
docker-compose -f production.yml up
```

both containers of Django & PostgreSQL run fine, the problem is which should I do first to make everything working on the test server, like everything working on the production server?
should I restore backup database first then run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

or should I migrate then restore backup database, actually I ran both, and each time after successfully end both I got this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /accounts/login/
```

so what should I do to restore backup database?

**Anther question:**
I tried to ignore the backup database and just run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and create a database from scratch but I got the same error as before!!!
I'm there is something common I'm wrong with, so help me with any information on the theory of backup database, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a pg_dump, you don't need to run `migrate.py`. The backup file will recreate all the tables and all the data in the tables. Before running `psql` to restore the data, you need to drop the database and re-create it. After you have created it and restored the file, you can then run a `migrate.py` whenever you make changes to your models.